# Batch Rename Files by Switching Two Parts of the Name

Tags: windows-10, powershell, script, rename, batch-rename

I'm new here and don't have any coding knowledge or experience or software, but I use Windows 10. I have LOTS of files named like:
(1) 2020-03-12.mp3
(7) 2021-04-10.mp4
(6) 2022-08-25.docx
etc.
They're mp4, mp3, jpg, pdf, docx, xlsx mostly. And I want to switch those elements elements around so like the first one would be named:
 2020-03-12 (1).mp3
Could you PLEASE help, thanks x

Comment: Does it have to be powershell or could it also be a batch script?

Comment: I don't know what any of them are. Just anything I can download for free!

Comment: @LaishanChan - i fall you want is to rename files without programming/scripting ...  take a look at the Bulk Rename utility >>> Bulk Rename Utility - Free File Renaming Software — https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do the job ... [*grin*]

the code ...

```
$TopDir = $env:TEMP

#region >>> make some files to work with
#    when ready to use the real items, remove the entire "#region/#endregion" block
@'
(1) 2020-03-12.mp3
(7) 2021-04-10.mp4
(6) 2022-08-25.docx
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine |
    ForEach-Object {
        # the "$Null =" is to supress unwanted output from the cmdlet
        $Null = New-Item -Path $TopDir -Name $_ -ItemType 'File' -Force
        }
#endregion >>> make some files to work with

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $TopDir -Filter '(*)*.*'

foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)
    {
    $NewBaseName = $FL_Item.BaseName -replace '^(.+)\s(.+)$', '$2 $1'
    $NewName = -join ($NewBaseName, $FL_Item.Extension)

    # remove the "-WhatIf" to make actual changes
    Rename-Item -Path $FL_Item.FullName -NewName $NewName -WhatIf
    }
```

what it does ...

- sets the source dir to work in
- creates a set of files to work on
  after you test this as-is, just remove the entire `#region/#endregion` block & set the `$TopDir` to your target folder.
- gets the list of files that start with `(*)`
- iterates thru that list
- creates a new BaseName for the file by capturing the two parts and switching them
- builds a new file name by joining the new BaseName and the old `.Extension`
- renames the file
  the current version of this script DOES NOT rename anything ... when you are ready to test that, remove or comment out the `-WhatIf` parameter at the end of the rename line.

output with `-WhatIf` ...

```
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\(1) 2020-03-12.mp3 Destination: C:\Temp\2020-03-12 (1).mp3".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\(6) 2022-08-25.docx Destination: C:\Temp\2022-08-25 (6).docx".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\(7) 2021-04-10.mp4 Destination: C:\Temp\2021-04-10 (7).mp4".
```

Comment: Thank you!! Is this powershell code?

Comment: you are most welcome ... and, yes, it is powershell code. save it to a file with `.ps1` as the extension, open it in the ISE, and run it. that will leave 3 files with the names in the `#region/#endregion` section in your temp dir. when you remove the `-WhatIf` & run the code, it will leave those 3 files with the new names.

Comment: Thank you, I will download it and try!! Thank you so much again

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, the operational Cmdlet will be [`Rename-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item).

To construct the new name, you can start with the *BaseName* property of the *System.IO.FileInfo* object returned by [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2).

Using the `Split` method, the BaseName can be split by the `<Space>` character, returning a two-element string array:

```
PS C:\>>'(1) 2020-03-12'.Split(' ')
(1)
2020-03-12
PS C:\>
```

To "assemble" the new name, there are several options, but I would recommend the [-f (Format operator)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f), which allows clear separation of constant and variable elements.

So a ScriptBlock to construct our new name with the current object in the pipeline will look like this:

```
{ '{1} {0}{2}' -f ( $_.BaseName.Split(' ') + $_.Extension )}
```

So if we assign that scfiptblock to a variable, we can use it in the rename operation. Assuming all files in the current directory follow the naming format and need to be renamed, these two lines will do the trick:

```
$NewNameLogic = { '{1} {0}{2}' -f ( $_.BaseName.Split(' ') + $_.Extension )}
Get-ChildItem -File | Rename-Item -NewName $NewNameLogic
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really appreciate you spending time figuring it out!!

Comment: You're welcome. There are so many choicee for string manipulation in **PowerShell**, it's good to become familiar with different paths to the same end... :D

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

for /f delims^= %%i in =;('where .:(*.*^|find /v "%~0"')do set "_name=%%~ni" & =;(
   cmd.exe /v /c "rename "%%~fi" "%%_name:* =%% !_name: %%_name:* =%%=!%%~xi"" );=
```

---

- For [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)/[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)

You can try using:

```
:: [ Replace Variable: (From Substring: Replace Variable = To Noting ) = To Nothing ] ::

:: define variable
>set "_var=(1) 2020-03-12" 

:: remove all before the first space            
>echo %_var:* =% 
2020-03-12

:: remove the inverse of [remove all before the first space]
>cmd /v /c "echo;!_var: %_var:* =%=!"
(1)

:: join the two replaces you have destination name
>cmd.exe /v /c "echo;!_var:* =! !_var: %_var:* =%=!.mp3"
2020-03-12 (1).mp3
```